# Detect last quotation mark

Tags: java, regex

I have some Json text response that I'm parsing through and need to pull out some values. Here's what I'm working with.

Inside a Json response I have something like this:

```
"createdOn": 1405536449291,
"updatedOn": 1405536511282,
"url": "https://www.myurl.com/path/v1/resource.json?parameter=test&parameter_2=\"JohnSmith\"",
...etc
```

I need to get these 3 values pulled out/captured (just the values, no quotation marks/commas that surround the Json values)

- `1405536449291`
- `1405536511282`
- `https://www.myurl.com/path/v1/resource.json?parameter=test&parameter_2=\"JohnSmith\"`

[Here is what I have so far.](http://ideone.com/88PCCO) As you can see, I'm really close. The `createdOn`, and `updatedOn` values are correct but the problem is that the first quotation mark around "JohnSmith" causes the regex to think it's done.

Is there any workaround to this problem that I'm missing? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using a regex rather than a JSON parser?

Comment: You can use GSON library to convert it into Java Object.

Comment: @JonSkeet I was using Regex to do the parsing because while I'm looping through looking for matches I'm adding it to a list since the order of the values matters.  There are other cases where I may have multiple sets of "createdOn", "updatedOn", and "url" values to get and add (though they'll always be in the same order)...that probably makes no sense, sorry.

Comment: Well wouldn't you still have the same ordering if you used a JSON parser? It feels like a no-brainer to me that if you're parsing JSON, you use a JSON parser...

Comment: Jon Skeet is right.. this does not make sense. You should use a JSON parser. It has built in all these problem solvers for you

Comment: Yeah, I'll switch. Any recommendation on a parser? Is Gson the way to go?

Answer (score -1):

<strike>Just removing the `\"` from the pattern should do it.</strike>

So

```
(?:url|createdOn|updatedOn)\":\\s\"?([^\",]*)
```

becomes

```
(?:url|createdOn|updatedOn)\":\\s\"?([^,]*)
```

So it stops at the comma instead of the quotation mark

Edit:

I noticed now that the string in the code you provided seems malformed. It sais:

```
\"https://www.myurl.com/path/v1/resource.json?parameter=test&parameter_2=\"JohnSmith\"
```

but it should say

```
\"https://www.myurl.com/path/v1/resource.json?parameter=test&parameter_2=\"JohnSmith\"\"
```

since there should be a quotation mark at the end of the URL as well.

In that case it can be solved with the following pattern:

```
(?:url|createdOn|updatedOn)\":\\s\"?(.*?)\"?,
```